# hibernate not-null property references a null or transient value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

everyone. I'm new to Hibernate and have some unexpected troubles with object persisting.
Here are relevant extracts from my Entity classes:

**TAnalysis.java**

```
public class TAnalysis implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer unAnalysis;

    @JoinColumn(name = "uninttest", referencedColumnName = "un_inttest", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TIntTest tIntTest;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "tAnalysis", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TBaseComp tBaseComp;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "tAnalysis", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TWellTest tWellTest;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "tAnalysis", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TGasPart tGasPart;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, mappedBy = "tAnalysis", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private TAddOnComp tAddOnComp;
}
```

**TIntTest.java**

```
public class TIntTest implements Serializable, ISimpleEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column (name = "un_inttest", nullable = false)
    private Integer unInttest;

    @OneToMany (cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "tIntTest")
    private Set<TAnalysis> tAnalysisSet;
}
```

**TBaseComp.java**

```
public class TBaseComp implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "un_analysis", nullable = false)
    private Integer unAnalysis;

    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "un_analysis", referencedColumnName = "un_analysis", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private TAnalysis tAnalysis;
}
```

Other classes (**TAddOnComp**, **TGasPart** and **TWellTest**) which have [@OneToOne] relationship with **TAnalysis** (kind of "subclasses") share the same structure with **TBaseComp**.

All listed relationships must be not-null. So when I persist new **TAnalysis** instance I must specify **TIntTest** object for it and also have to create "subclass" instances. That's how I do it:

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
TAnalysis an = new TAnalysis();
TBaseComp baseComp = new TBaseComp();
TGasPart gasPart = new TGasPart();
TAddOnComp addInComp = new TAddOnComp();
TWellTest wellTest = new TWellTest();

an.setTBaseComp(baseComp);
an.setTGasPart(gasPart);
an.setTAddOnComp(addInComp);
an.setTWellTest(wellTest);

baseComp.setTAnalysis(an);
gasPart.setTAnalysis(an);
addInComp.setTAnalysis(an);
wellTest.setTAnalysis(an);

TIntTest intTest = em.find(TIntTest.class, 10);
an.setTIntTest(intTest);

an = em.merge(an);
//baseComp = em.merge(baseComp);
//gasPart = em.merge(gasPart);
//addOnComp = em.merge(addOnComp);
//wellTest = em.merge(wellTest);
//em.persist(an);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

Merge operation throws an exception

```
org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value :   org.foladesoft.omnibus_client_maven.entities.TAnalysis.tIntTest"
```

I can't understand why this happens because I specify requered property value `an.setTIntTest(intTest)`;

Trying to solve my problem I used `em.persist(an)` instead of merge but got another exception in **commit** phase: PostgreSQL's *foreign key violation exception* told me that I'm trying to insert record into **TAddOnComp** before inserting new record into **TAnalysis**.

Could you please tell me why I encountered these problems and how I can make my application work.

Comment: I recommen debugging whether em.find returns a non-null TIntTest. Also, get Hibernate to log the update query including params.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as this is a new Entity you should be calling:

```
em.persist(an);
```

The reason you get the FK violation when calling em.persist(an) is that TAddOnComp knows nothing about it's associated TAnalysis and so it cannot insert the FK.

For bi-directional relationships you **always** need to maintain both sides of the relationship in your in-memory model. TAddOnComp would then have a reference to its associated TAnalysis and the insert operation can get and insert the FK accordingly.

```
TAnalysis an = new TAnalysis();
an.setTBaseComp(baseComp);
an.setTGasPart(gasPart);
//etc
baseComp.setAnalysis(an);
gasPart.setAnalysis(an);
//etc
em.persist(an);
```

Ideally you should encapsulate these operations:

```
public class TAnalysis implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer unAnalysis;

    private TAddOnComp tAddOnComp;

    public void setTAddOnComp(TAddOnComp tAddOnComp){
        this.tAddOnComp = tAddOnComp;

        if(! tAddOnComp.getTAnalysis != this){
            tAddOnComp.setTAnalysis(this);
        }

        // and do the same on the other side of the relationship
    }
}
```